# How to share my wordpress posts into instagram

Tags: wordpress

Does anyone has an idea how to use **instagram api** for sharing photos from my WordPress site into my instagram account?

Answer (score 13):

According to [Instagram](http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/media/):

At this time, uploading via the API is not possible. We made a conscious choice not to add this for the following reasons:

- Instagram is about your life on the go – we hope to encourage photos from within the app. However, in the future we may give whitelist access to individual apps on a case by case basis.
- We want to fight spam & low quality photos. Once we allow uploading from other sources, it's harder to control what comes into the Instagram ecosystem. All this being said, we're working on ways to ensure users have a consistent and high-quality experience on our platform.

Therefore, currently you cannot upload photos from your wordpress site into your instagram account.

Comment: What the hell is sharethis saying they can do this? They must be misleading their users http://support.sharethis.com/customer/portal/questions/974402-instagram#sthash.uBisXZyB.dpbs

Comment: Found an article on this that talks about a WordPress plugin called SNAP (requires paid "pro" version) that built an API for it: https://wordpress.org/plugins/social-networks-auto-poster-facebook-twitter-g/