# How to add instagram share link to wordpress post

Tags: wordpress, instagram

I want to add Instagram share link to my wordpress single post page.

Is it possible or not (https://stackoverflow.com/a/23196163/4073217)?

If yes then how to add link for sharing wordpress post to instagram?

**EDIT**

I'm trying to add instagram link as below

```
<li class=""><a href="instagram://send?text=<?php echo $currentUrl; ?>" data-action="share/instagram/share" target="_blank"><i class="icon-instagram"></i></a></li>
```

but it is not working.

Comment: you want to add follow or share link?

Comment: How to add both links?

Comment: I am using plugin : https://www.blog2social.com/en/faq/content/2/19/en/how-do-i-connect-blog2social-with-instagram.html

Comment: https://wpwarfare.com/display-instagram-on-wordpress/

Comment: let me know if you want to know anything else

Comment: Thanks for reply, but can you please tell the code only for instagram social link from the plugin? as I'm using a theme which has social share share option inbuilt (except instagram) and don't want to change other social links.

Comment: I can't tell you theme specific theme you have to ask author

Comment: Please check my edit part, I'm trying to add code in `post.php` and I was asking the Instagram code from the plugin `blog2social` so that I can implement that into `post.php`.

Comment: You have to check single.php file